# What should "s=std::move(s);" do when s is a string?

Tags: c++

This (`s=std::move(s)`)came up in a recent question I asked. The consensus was that self assignment from an rvalue to an lvalue should be checked and prevented much like a regular self assignment `s=s`.  To me this seems like unnecessary additional code as I can't imagine where an rvalue self assignment would occur. But I tested this code with GCC, CLANG, and MSVC to see what the default move assignment did.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::string s{"asdfasdfasdfasdf"};
    s=std::move(s);
    std::cout << "String is: " << s << '\n';
}
```

GCC and CLANG changed s to a null string.
MSVC didn't modify s. Which is correct or is this UB?

*Note:* thanks to the person(s) that identified a duplicate, it's clear the answer is that GCC, CLANG, and MSVC are all correct. Different results are permitted and it's not UB!  Wow. Go read the links.

[compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/7saxd4bK8)

GCC and CLANG output self assignment warnings like this.

> warning: moving 's' of type 'std::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string'} to itself [-Wself-move]

Comment: Thanks to those that identified the dup.

Comment: clang's `-Wself-move` might help.

Comment: @Eljay More a curiosity. I can't think of any actual use case where the rvalue would have the same address as the assignee. Seems to be born out by the dup.